# how to give store url for phtml pages

Tags: magento-1.9, url

If we click on one link, we  have to display the following url

http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/

i can use the code like this :

```
<a href = "http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/">click</a>
```

but i think this is not good practice

I am trying this ,

```
<a href = '{{store direct_url="marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/"}} '>
```

but its not working.

Comment: did not understand your point

Comment: @AmitBera i updated the question...

Comment: did you working in cms pages?

Comment: @QaisarSatti phtml pages only.

Comment: if it's cmspage/static block use this{{store url='marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new'}}

Comment: then use above code you are using the cms blocks code.

Comment: @QaisarSatti can i use like this : <a href="<?php echo this->getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/'); ?>">Click here</a> because getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';'"

Comment: <?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/'); ?>  use this

Comment: @BabyinMagento2 my mistake use latest code..

Comment: <a href ="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/'); ?>">click</a>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you working in `phtml` file you can use this code for `url`

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/new/'); ?>
```

Comment: can you able to see this link : http://2.kidsdial.com/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/editprofile/ or are you getting maintanance mode ?

Comment: can u provide login credential

Comment: means , you can see this site , right : http://2.kidsdial.com/ ?

Comment: yes i can see that. but the page you asking need login to see.